# Mac Terminal script: commands inside program

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, sh, ampl

I want to run a program inside terminal using a .sh script and make the script give commands to the program. This is my code:

```
echo "running ampl"
ampl
include test.run.txt;
python outConverter.py
```

The line `include test.run.txt;` is the command I want to run inside AMPL, but the script stops when I have opened AMPL:

[Terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBwbX.png)

Comment: Interactively when you run `ampl` it takes over your terminal input. That doesn't happen in a script. That is it either exits because there is no input or it still takes over your input but that doesn't come from later lines in the script. (Which is what you show in your screenshot. A copy and paste would have been much more useful by the way.) You need to see how `ampl` can be given commands to run in a non-interactive fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass input to AMPL (or any other command) by [redirecting input](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) as follows:

```
echo "running ampl"
ampl << EOF
include test.run.txt;
EOF
python outConverter.py
```

This particular case can be simplified to just

```
echo "running ampl"
ampl test.run.txt
python outConverter.py
```

because you can pass the names of AMPL files to process as command-line arguments.